# Change SEQUENCE of boolean values [True, False, False...] to bit string sequence

Tags: python, pandas, bit, huffman-code

**Question 1**

I have a data frame that I adapted from a dictionary I made after using Huffman algo on a text file. I converted my dictionary to a data frame but it changed my bitarray values to True's and False's and I would like to keep them as 1'a and 0's.

This is a snippet of what my dictionary looked like:

```
Huffman Dictionary 
{',': bitarray('0000'), 'k': bitarray('0001000'), '-': bitarray('000100100'), '?': bitarray('000100101'), 'A': bitarray('000100110')}
```

And here is a snippet of what my data frame looks like:

```
Huffman Data Frame 
       character                                          bitString
    0          ,                       [False, False, False, False]
    1          k   [False, False, False, True, False, False, False]
    2          -  [False, False, False, True, False, False, True...
    3          ?  [False, False, False, True, False, False, True...
    4          A  [False, False, False, True, False, False, True...
```

Here is some code that i've developed:

```
huffmanDictionary = {a[0]:bitarray(str(a[1])) for a in huffmanList}
    print("\n Huffman Dictionary \n")
    print(huffmanDictionary, "\n")

    encodedText = bitarray()
    encodedText.encode(huffmanDictionary, textFile)

    print("\n Encoded text \n")
    print(encodedText)

    print("\n Length of encoded text: ", len(encodedText), "\n")

    # making data frame to put the dictionary in for easier readability
    columnNames = ['character', 'bitString']
    huffDataframe = pd.DataFrame(list(huffmanDictionary.items()), columns = columnNames)
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!! Thanks!

**Question 2**

Also not sure if its possible, but could the [] be removed as well as the commas in the bitstring column of the data frame once changed back to 1's and 0's?

Comment: The obvious (naive?) answer is `bitarray(str(''.join(('1' if v else '0') for v in seq)))`

Comment: sorry not quite sure i follow, do you mean replace what i have originally for bitarray in huffmanDictionary with the above code? @CharlesDuffy

Comment: Nope -- the above was speaking strictly to the question asked in the title, not looking at the context below. If your real question is about changing how pandas stringifies a dataframe, that's not something I'm in a position to speak to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, @Charles Duffy means to declare your dictionary as follows:

```
huffmanDictionary = {a[0]:bitarray(str(''.join(('1' if v else '0') for v in a[1]))) for a in huffmanList}
```

Also you could do something like this once you have created your dataframe:

```
def bool_to_bit(s):
    r = ''
    for i in s:
        if i:
            r += '1'
        else:
            r += '0'
    return r

df['bitString'].apply(bool_to_bit)
```

Comment: I tried your bool_to_bits and it's removed my column 'character'... any thoughts why?

Comment: it did change everything back to bits though so that part worked!!

Comment: reassign to the same column so, `df['bitString'] = df['bitString'].apply(bool_to_bit)`

Comment: i did! i just joined stack overflow though so my rep isn't high enough to allow my up votes to  be seen publicly yet :( but my up vote was recorded!!

Comment: ok but click the checkmark underneath so that the question can be closed